# Rank result set according to condition

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, rank

I have a table which has 3 columns: Product, Date, Status

I want to rank in this manner:
for each product order by Date, and Rank if Status = FALSE then 0, if it's TRUE then start ranking by 1, continue ranking by the same value if previous Status is TRUE.

In this ordered set if FALSE comes assign to it 0, and for the next coming TRUE status for same product assign x+1 (x here is previous rank value for status TRUE).

I hope picture makes it more clear

[image]

Comment: @HABO, don't think that you are the smartest one here. I always try to come up with solution before posting here, but non of my tries seemed to me reasonable. If you don't wish to help just pass through

Comment: I'm _far_ from the smartest here. My understanding of SO was that it was not a code writing service, but a place to seek help after attempting to solve a problem on one's own. As such, it makes sense to include some indication of the effort you've made, e.g. a query that didn't quite work. That allows the highly compensated volunteers to assist you at an appropriate level. The explanation for a down vote starts with "This question does not show any research effort... ." I still don't see any research effort in this question. (Ref: [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Comment: @HABO, I didn't post research to here just not to bring much overhead to here, since problem is too specific, but here it is: I've created two extra columns rn - row number partitioned by product where Status is TRUE, rn2 - row number partitioned by product. After doing so I let the rows enter into two while loops: first one controls product, second rn2, and by "if" manipulations, I putted desired values into rank column. But that works too slow, since I have 2 mln rows, so I wanted to learn some other view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses SS2008R2 features which do not include `LEAD`/`LAG`. A better solution is certainly possible with more modern versions of SQL Server.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Product VarChar(10), ProductDate Date,
  ProductStatus Bit, DesiredRank Int );
insert into @Samples values
  ( 'a', '20160525', 0, 0 ), ( 'a', '20160526', 1, 1 ), ( 'a', '20160529', 1, 1 ),
  ( 'a', '20160601', 1, 1 ), ( 'a', '20160603', 0, 0 ), ( 'a', '20160604', 0, 0 ),
  ( 'a', '20160611', 1, 2 ), ( 'a', '20160612', 0, 0 ), ( 'a', '20160613', 1, 3 ),
  ( 'b', '20160521', 1, 1 ), ( 'b', '20160522', 0, 0 ), ( 'b', '20160525', 1, 2 );
select * from @Samples;

-- Query to rank data as requested.
with WithRN as (
  select Product, ProductDate, ProductStatus, DesiredRank,
    Row_Number() over ( partition by Product order by ProductDate ) as RN
    from @Samples
  ),
  RCTE as (
  select *, Cast( ProductStatus as Int ) as C
    from WithRN
    where RN = 1
  union all
  select WRN.*, C + Cast( 1 - R.ProductStatus as Int ) * Cast( WRN.ProductStatus as Int )
    from RCTE as R inner join
      WithRN as WRN on WRN.Product = R.Product and WRN.RN = R.RN + 1 )
  select Product, ProductDate, ProductStatus, DesiredRank,
    C * ProductStatus as CalculatedRank
    from RCTE
    order by Product, ProductDate;
```

Note that the sample data was extracted from an image using a Mark I Eyeball. Had the OP taken heed of advice [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) it would have been somewhat easier.

Tip: Using column names that don't happen to match data types and keywords makes life somewhat simpler.

Comment: thank you, that works. It fails due to "maximum recursion 100" error, but that is my fault, I've not stated the volume in the post. I would rather continue looping.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query,

```
SELECT  a.Product ,
    a.Date ,
    a.Status ,
    CASE WHEN a.Status = 'FALSE' THEN 0
         ELSE 1
    END [Rank]
```

FROM    ( SELECT    Product ,
                    Date ,
                    Status ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY DATE, Status ) RNK
          FROM      TableProduct
        ) a
ORDER BY Product, a.RNK

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but query is very different from what I need